# Google Maps Android API license for free-to-play game

Tags: android, google-maps, licensing

It isn't clearly stated in Google Maps Terms of Service whether I can use it for free in a free-to-play game.

I know it's not really freemium or something like this, so please tell me - do I have to buy a license for my game?

Answer (score 1):

> Disclaimer: this is lot legal advice.

According to [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/), your app fits in the freemium section of the "Paid" category, and so you are allowed to use the SDK for free, respecting the limits. Quoting the doc:

> "Apps or websites that require an end user or organization to pay a fee for download or access (e.g. freemium, OEM or subscription). [...] Standard Plan: For Android/iOS, you may charge a fee via the Play or App stores for your app and use the Standard Plan."

Your freemium app fits in the "Standard", as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/#details)

In the first page of the documentation, it is clear that, as long as your app or content (like a webpage page) is accessible to the general public, you are allowed to use the maps api without paying anything to Google.